# If alternative nucleotide leads to missense mutation

Tags: r, sequence, fasta

I'm trying to compare large sequence data with and without SNPs and mark snps as non-synonymous or synonymous. I have `.fasta` sequence and `.bim` file from PLNIK with conservative (refference) and alternative nucleotides.:

```
head(test)

  pos ALT REF
1   2   G   T
2   8   G   T
3  65   C   G
4  68   C   G
5  77   T   C
6  78   G   C
```

I can replace refference nucleotides with alternatrive ones:

```
ref[test$pos]=as.vector(test$ALT)
```

I need to say, will replacement lead to aminoacid change or not. I thougth to use `seqinr` package, maybe I'm on a wrong way?
So I've 2 strings, which are sequences (alternative nucleotides in `alt` vector are marked with upper register):

```
ref=c("a","t","g","t","c","g","t","c","g","g","c","c","g","c","g","g","g","c",
"c","a","a","g","a","c","a","a","c","g","g","a","g","a","t","a","c","c",
"g","c","t","g","g","g","g","a","c","t","a","c","a","t","c","a","a","g",
"t","g","g","a","t","g","t","g","c","g","g","c","g","c","c","g","g","t",
"g","g","c","c","g","t","g","c","g","g","g","c","g","g","c","g","c","c",
"a","t","g","g","c","c","a","a","c","c","t","c","c","a","g","c","g","c",
"g","g","c","g","t","t","g","g","c","t","c","c","c","t","c","g","t","c",
"c","g","t","g","a","c","a","t","t","g","g","c","g","a","c","c","c","c",
"t","g","c","c","t","c","a","a","c","c","c","a","t","c","c","c","c","c",
"g","t","t","a","a","g")

alt=c("a","G","g","t","c","g","t","G","g","g","c","c","g","c","g","g","g","c",
"c","a","a","g","a","c","a","a","c","g","g","a","g","a","t","a","c","c",
"g","c","t","g","g","g","g","a","c","t","a","c","a","t","c","a","a","g",
"t","g","g","a","t","g","t","g","c","g","C","c","g","C","c","g","g","t",
"g","g","c","c","T","G","g","c","g","g","C","c","g","g","c","g","c","c",
"a","t","g","g","c","c","a","a","c","c","t","c","c","a","g","c","g","c",
"g","g","c","g","t","t","g","g","c","t","C","c","c","t","c","g","C","c",
"c","T","t","g","a","c","a","T","t","g","g","c","g","a","c","c","c","c",
"t","g","c","c","t","c","a","a","c","c","c","a","t","c","c","c","C","c",
"g","t","t","a","a","g")
```

I can translate this vectors into aminoacids:

```
t_ref=translate(ref)
t_alt=translate(alt)
```

Then I can compare them and say which've changed:

```
which((ref==alt)==FALSE)
which((t_ref==t_alt)==FALSE)
```

So the question is to mark nucleotides in `test` df which leads to aminoacid change. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use modulo arithmetic to construct positions in the protein sequence from the `pos` column of the nucleotide sequence

```
library(seqinr)
test$pos %/% 3  # returns a zero-based position, so add 1 to get 1 based value
#[1]  0  2 21 22 25 26
t_ref[ 1+(test$pos %/% 3)]
#[1] "M" "S" "G" "A" "R" "A"  # lookup value in prot-seq
t_alt[ 1+(test$pos %/% 3)]
#[1] "R" "W" "A" "A" "L" "A"  # test for equality to this value
test$change  <- t_ref[ 1+((test$pos-1) %/% 3)] == t_alt[ 1+((test$pos-1) %/% 3)]
test
 #=====================
  pos ALT REF change
1   2   G   T  FALSE
2   8   G   T  FALSE
3  65   C   G  FALSE
4  68   C   G   TRUE
5  77   T   C  FALSE
6  78   G   C  FALSE
```

I got the "registration" of the modulo arithmetic wrong on my first try, noting that this is a properly "registered" translation:

```
> (1:21 -1) %/% 3
 [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6
```

Comment: Yeah, that works pretty well if SNPs aren't near, but It doesn't if SNPs are near, e.g. pos 77 and 78, if it happens we mark both SNPs as 'FALSE'

Comment: You didn't say what the "right" answer was going to be and I cannot understand the terms "near" and "far" in this context. If it's failing, then it's not due to the distance from hte origin. I might have gotten the "registration" of the modulo arithmetic wrong. See if this test is better: `test$change  <- t_ref[ 1+((test$pos-1) %/% 3)] == t_alt[ 1+((test$pos-1) %/% 3)]`

Comment: But anyway, You solved my problem, I just added an exception rule for neighboring SNPs, thanks a lot!